# What is better in cassandra many tables of same structure or one table with many rows

Tags: cassandra, cql, bigdata

Suppose that I have 1000 entities with exactly the same structure. For example all entities have three fields:

```
String id;
String name;
int amount;
```

Also I expect that there will be huge amount of every type of entity in the system.

So I have two variants right now:

1. For each entity create separate table which looks like:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE <SOME_ENTITY_NAME> (
       id text PRIMARY KEY,
       name text,
       amount int
   )
   ```
2. I'll create only one table but with composite priamry key:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ALL_ENTITIES_TABLE (
       entity_name text,
       id text,
       name text,
       amount int,
       PRIMARY KEY ((entity_name, id))
   );
   ```

Of course, supporting only one table is more simplier, but what is with performance?

So, the question is what variant is better in terms of performance, taking into account that each type of entity will have millions(may be billions) of records?

Comment: what will be your access pattern... anyways second approach is much better.... `WHERE entity_name='' and id=''` will be efficiently handled by second table... if you have different use case... share your use case

Answer (score 2):

There is a limitation on the number of the tables that can be created in the Cassandra cluster. Usual recommendation is too keep this number lower than 200, with ~500 is like a "hard stop"...

The reason for this is that every table requires allocation of additional memory, and other resources to keep auxiliary data, like, key/row caches, bloom filters, etc. Depending on the Cassandra version, every table may require 1-2Mb of memory.

So in your case, the 2nd design is better because you keep all data in single table, and your partition key will allow to spread data evenly between nodes of cluster.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the first approach is incorrect in terms of maintainability. Too much of dynamically created tables should be tough to maintain. Also, If you use your partitioning/clustering order properly (as per the need of data retrieval) it should be easier and efficient to query. Also if you are using 3.x version of Cassandra, secondary indexes can come in handy.

NOTE: Secondary indexes don't allow sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra was designed around the fact that disk space is the cheapest resource among all. You must build your data model around the queries that you will be using the most regardless of whether this model would consume more disk space or not - as long as it serves the purpose of your queries in the most efficient way. I wouldn't be able to answer your question without taking a look at the queries you will be using. In general, you must feel free to create as many tables as needed as long as it serves the purpose of your queries. I would recommend having a look [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling).

Comment: You can't have as many tables as possible if it comes to numbers greater than several hundreds...